# Android Kotlin net.openid:appauth - capturing token after firing intent with getAuthorizationRequestIntent

Tags: android, kotlin, appauth

I am trying to make sense on how to use android's AppAuth library based on the different examples that showcase different use cases of this library. I haven't managed to grasp what it requires for it to work. I also had a look at their docs

my approach:

Call the fetchFromIssuer method, this method is passed the discovery doc uri, which when called is successful. From this discovery doc, i use the authorisation endpoint and token endpoint to configure a new service like so:

```
val authServConfig = AuthorizationServiceConfiguration(
            authEndpoint /* from discovery doc */,
            tokenEndpoint /* from discovery doc */,
        )
```

More configuration is performed, then when the intent is fired and a browser is launched to enter the details, once these details are entered and sign in is performed, I am redirected back to the app launch screen. At this point I don't know how to go about intercepting this token or whether or not the authentication was succesfull.

the code for the intent:

```
val authServ = AuthorizationService(applicationContext)

            try {
                val authIntent = authServ.getAuthorizationRequestIntent(authRequest)

                startActivity(authIntent)
```

The intent is successful but the redirect after authenticating I don't know where it goes.

The examples I have come across with this app have invoved:

downloading an example project which when downloaded and launched using android studio, error upon error, nothing works.

I chose to work with this example but again no luck: [codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/appauth-android-codelab/#0)

Answer (score 0):

With AppAuth, if you have not worked with token authorisation comfortably you may find it somewhat challenging to use this library. I also have to say it does some heavy lifting and gives you some mechanisms out of the box to work with.

Configure the library as recommended or how you want to use it.

My approach so far is to have one wrapper class that will manage the instances for the Service and State (for now).

The part were I was stuck is because I was missing the **RedirectUriReceiverActivity**. It is this activity's intent result you get to work with in **onActivityResult**. It is in here you handle the response from the browser intent (After user successfully acquires a token).

Also don't forget to handle when the user chooses to dismiss the intent.

Regarding the refresh token. The library has **performActionWithFreshTokens** method on authsate.

Comment: did you use ClientSecret as well? And how you handle refresh token?